# Windows Event Log VBS script no result

Tags: vbscript, event-log

We have powershell scripts setup for preforming offline backups. The executing of these scripts was failing due to an incorrect script execution causing powershell to prompt what user wants to do. Due to this the scripts timed out.

To detect script execution timeouts i'm trying to query the event log with a VBS script, but this allways returns 0 results.

I tried with this code:

```
 LOG_FILE = "C:\jsco\Scripts\output.txt"

strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational' AND EventCode = '332'")
For Each objEvent in colItems     
    writeLog "Category: " & objEvent.Category
    writeLog "Category String: " & objEvent.CategoryString
    writeLog "Computer Name: " & objEvent.ComputerName
    writeLog "Data: " & objEvent.Data
    writeLog "Event Code: " & objEvent.EventCode
    writeLog "Event Identifier: " & objEvent.EventIdentifier
    writeLog "Insertion Strings: " & objEvent.InsertionStrings
    writeLog "Logfile: " & objEvent.Logfile
    writeLog "Message: " & objEvent.Message
    writeLog "Record Number: " & objEvent.RecordNumber
    writeLog "Source Name: " & objEvent.SourceName
    writeLog "Time Generated: " & objEvent.TimeGenerated
    writeLog "Time Written: " & objEvent.TimeWritten
    writeLog "Type: " & objEvent.Type
    writeLog "User: " & objEvent.User 
Next

Sub writeLog(strText)
  Dim objFSO, objLogFile

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
  Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LOG_FILE, 8, True)

  objLogFile.WriteLine strText
  objLogFile.Close
End Sub
```

I allso tried this with:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

And:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{(Security)}\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

As shown on the screencap, the event is defenatly in the the Event Log.

[image: Eventlog Screencap]
<sub>(source: [jef at 149.210.139.155](http://149.210.139.155/%7Ejef/tmp/eventlog.png))</sub>

Does anyone have any idea what causes this and on how to fix this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Selecting from an eventlog can take a very long time, what is the timeout set on the scheduled task?  (in taskschd.msc, what is the timeout specified in "Stop the task if it runs longer than" on the Settings tab?)

Comment: Hi, thx for your comment. The query's can indeed take a very long time, but i can notice that it does not return any results because it writes nothing to the output file. When i try with the query `SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent` it start writing output but this is offcourse not the result i need. I tried to verify that the event ID is in the results with a DISTINCT but this does not seem to be supported as i get NULL result.

Comment: Right...but the query will return 0 results if it times out before results have arrived:  what is the value in the "stop task if it runs longer than" field on the settings tab?